# The constructors of every class in an SDK (written in objective-c and imported to swift through a bridging header) are returning nil

Tags: objective-c, swift, constructor, bridging-header

Disclaimer: I don't have any experience with Swift. The problem can be as simple as a missing comma, and I still wouldn't know.

Here is the way I am constructing the object:

```
var request: PaymentRequest?
request = PaymentRequest()
```

I also tried this:

```
var request = PaymentRequest()
```

The second option appears to delay the problem, somehow. Instead of immediately showing a nil value, it pretends to construct an instance with a memory address of `0x0000000000000000`, and the application still crashes further down the code:

```
        // This is OK
        request.add("some key", "some value")
        ...
        request.add("some key", "some value")
        let services = PaymentService()
        let response = services.process(request)

        // Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
        let responseCode = response.get("Response.StatusCode")
```

Here is how `PaymentRequest.h` looks like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface PaymentRequest : NSObject
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *userInterface;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSMutableDictionary *authenticationToken;
@property (nonatomic,strong)NSMutableDictionary *keyValueDictionary;
+ (PaymentRequest *)sharedManager;
- (void)add :(NSString *)key :(NSString *)value;
- (void)setPaymentType :(NSString *)value;
- (void)setPaymentAuthenticationToken :(NSString *)key valueForKey:(id)value;
- (void)isLogging :(BOOL)userValue;
@end
```

Since I wasn't sure how bridging headers work, I tried importing every header in the SDK instead of only the ones I needed, but that didn't help, either.

Comment: It looks like PaymentRequest is a singleton. Try `PaymentRequest.sharedManager()`

Comment: `let request = PaymentRequest.sharedManager()` returns nil on the first access to `request` (unless I am using the method improperly). Nonetheless, it makes no sense for a class representing a web request to be a singleton, does it?

Comment: Good point. A singleton doesn't really make sense here.

Comment: For me it's looks like you have have local and instance/class variables with same name